How to stop camera reset when Google Map Widget updates in Flutter
I am working on a Live tracking widget using google maps for flutter. I am using Firebase for the streambuilder and an updateLocation function that periodicly (currently every 10 sec) will fetch the current device location and then update the "driverLocation" field in the "ShipmentDetails" document within Firebase. When this is updated the streambuilder should rebuild and regenerate the new polylines. This all currently works.
The Problems:

Camera control for the widget is locked for a second upon update, how do I stop this and provide a smooth user experience where the map updates without reseting camera position?

How do I ensure the streambuilder rebuilds in web and polylines are displayed correctly?


CODE FOR MOBILE:
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/schema/enums/enums.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' hide LatLng;

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' as latlng;
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' as latlng;

import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

class RouteViewLiveExperiment extends StatefulWidget {
  const RouteViewLiveExperiment({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.lineColor = Colors.black,
    this.startAddress,
    this.destinationAddress,
    required this.startCoordinate,
    required this.endCoordinate,
    required this.iOSGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.androidGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.webGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.rideDetailsReference,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final Color lineColor;
  final String? startAddress;
  final String? destinationAddress;
  final LatLng startCoordinate;
  final LatLng endCoordinate;
  final String iOSGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final String androidGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final String webGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final DocumentReference rideDetailsReference;

  @override
  _RouteViewLiveExperimentState createState() =>
      _RouteViewLiveExperimentState();
}

class _RouteViewLiveExperimentState extends State<RouteViewLiveExperiment> {
  late final CameraPosition _initialLocation;
  GoogleMapController? mapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};
  Timer? _timer;

  // PolylinePoints polylinePoints;
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> initialPolylines = {};
  String get googleMapsApiKey {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return widget.webGoogleMapsApiKey;
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return '';
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return widget.iOSGoogleMapsApiKey;
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return widget.androidGoogleMapsApiKey;
      default:
        return widget.webGoogleMapsApiKey;
    }
  }

  // Method for calculating the distance between two places
  Future<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>?> _calculateDistance({
    required double startLatitude,
    required double startLongitude,
    required double destinationLatitude,
    required double destinationLongitude,
  }) async {
    if (markers.isNotEmpty) markers.clear();

    try {
      String startCoordinatesString = '($startLatitude, $startLongitude)';
      String destinationCoordinatesString =
          '($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)';

      // Destination Location Marker
      Marker destinationMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(destinationCoordinatesString),
        position: latlng.LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Destination $destinationCoordinatesString',
          snippet: widget.destinationAddress ?? '',
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      );

      // Adding the markers to the list
      //markers.add(startMarker);
      markers.add(destinationMarker);

      debugPrint(
        'MAP::START COORDINATES: ($startLatitude, $startLongitude)',
      );
      debugPrint(
        'MAP::DESTINATION COORDINATES: ($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)',
      );
      double miny = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? startLatitude
          : destinationLatitude;
      double minx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? startLongitude
          : destinationLongitude;
      double maxy = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? destinationLatitude
          : startLatitude;
      double maxx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? destinationLongitude
          : startLongitude;

      double southWestLatitude = miny;
      double southWestLongitude = minx;

      double northEastLatitude = maxy;
      double northEastLongitude = maxx;

      mapController?.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
            northeast: latlng.LatLng(northEastLatitude, northEastLongitude),
            southwest: latlng.LatLng(southWestLatitude, southWestLongitude),
          ),
          60.0,
        ),
      );

      final result = await _createPolylines(
        startLatitude,
        startLongitude,
        destinationLatitude,
        destinationLongitude,
      );

      final polylines = result.item1;
      final polylineCoordinates = result.item2;

      double totalDistance = 0.0;

      for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
        totalDistance += _coordinateDistance(
          polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude,
        );
      }

      final placeDistance = totalDistance.toStringAsFixed(2);
      debugPrint('MAP::DISTANCE: $placeDistance km');
      FFAppState().routeDistance = '$placeDistance km';

      var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=$destinationLatitude,$destinationLongitude&origins=$startLatitude,$startLongitude&key=$googleMapsApiKey',
      );
      var response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

        final String durationText =
            jsonResponse['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
        debugPrint('MAP::$durationText');
        FFAppState().routeDuration = '$durationText';
      } else {
        debugPrint('ERROR in distance matrix API');
      }

      return polylines;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }

  double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

  Future<Tuple2<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>, List<latlng.LatLng>>>
      _createPolylines(
    double startLatitude,
    double startLongitude,
    double destinationLatitude,
    double destinationLongitude,
  ) async {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleApiKey: googleMapsApiKey,
      request: PolylineRequest(
          origin: PointLatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
          destination: PointLatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
          mode: TravelMode.driving),
    );

    List<latlng.LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(latlng.LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    }

    PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: widget.lineColor,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 3,
    );

    return Tuple2({id: polyline}, polylineCoordinates);
  }

  initPolylines() async {
    double startLatitude = widget.startCoordinate.latitude;
    double startLongitude = widget.startCoordinate.longitude;

    double destinationLatitude = widget.endCoordinate.latitude;
    double destinationLongitude = widget.endCoordinate.longitude;
    final initPolylines = await _calculateDistance(
      startLatitude: startLatitude,
      startLongitude: startLongitude,
      destinationLatitude: destinationLatitude,
      destinationLongitude: destinationLongitude,
    );
    if (initPolylines != null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
          (_) => setState(() => initialPolylines = initPolylines));
    }
  }

  void updateLocation() async {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
      LatLng currentUserLocationValue = await getCurrentUserLocation(
        defaultLocation: const LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
      );

      final rideUpdateData = createShipmentDetailsRecordData(
        driverLocation: currentUserLocationValue,
      );

      await widget.rideDetailsReference.update(
        rideUpdateData,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final startCoordinate = latlng.LatLng(
      widget.startCoordinate.latitude,
      widget.startCoordinate.longitude,
    );
    _initialLocation = CameraPosition(
      target: startCoordinate,
      zoom: 14,
    );
    updateLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ShipmentDetailsRecord>(
      stream: ShipmentDetailsRecord.getDocument(widget.rideDetailsReference),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            height: widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            child: GoogleMap(
              markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
              initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(initialPolylines.values),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                mapController = controller;
                initPolylines();
              },
            ),
          );
        }

        final rideRecord = snapshot.data;
        debugPrint('MAP::UPDATED');

        return Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          child: FutureBuilder<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>?>(
              future: _calculateDistance(
                startLatitude: rideRecord!.driverLocation!.latitude,
                startLongitude: rideRecord.driverLocation!.longitude,
                destinationLatitude: rideRecord.destinationLocation!.latitude,
                destinationLongitude: rideRecord.destinationLocation!.longitude,
              ),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return GoogleMap(
                    markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: latlng.LatLng(
                        rideRecord.driverLocation!.latitude,
                        rideRecord.driverLocation!.longitude,
                      ),
                      zoom: 14,
                    ),
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(initialPolylines.values),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      mapController = controller;
                    },
                  );
                }

                return GoogleMap(
                  markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: latlng.LatLng(
                      rideRecord.driverLocation!.latitude,
                      rideRecord.driverLocation!.longitude,
                    ),
                    zoom: 14,
                  ),
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(snapshot.data!.values),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    mapController = controller;
                  },
                );
              }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

CODE FOR WEB:
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/schema/enums/enums.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:companywebsite/backend/api_requests/api_calls.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' hide LatLng;

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' as latlng;

import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

class RouteViewLiveCopy extends StatefulWidget {
  const RouteViewLiveCopy({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.startCoordinate,
    required this.endCoordinate,
    this.lineColor = Colors.black,
    required this.iOSGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.androidGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.webGoogleMapsApiKey,
    required this.rideDetailsReference,
    required this.rebuildPage,
    required this.positions,
    required this.defaultImageUrl,
    required this.startImageUrl,
    required this.destinationImageUrl,
    this.startAddress,
    this.destinationAddress,
    this.waypoints,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final LatLng startCoordinate;
  final LatLng endCoordinate;
  final Color lineColor;
  final String iOSGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final String androidGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final String webGoogleMapsApiKey;
  final DocumentReference rideDetailsReference;
  final String? startAddress;
  final String? destinationAddress;
  final Future<dynamic> Function() rebuildPage;
  final List<MarkersStruct> positions;
  final String defaultImageUrl;
  final String startImageUrl;
  final String destinationImageUrl;
  final List<LatLng>? waypoints;

  @override
  _RouteViewLiveCopyState createState() => _RouteViewLiveCopyState();
}

class _RouteViewLiveCopyState extends State<RouteViewLiveCopy> {
  late final CameraPosition _initialLocation;
  GoogleMapController? mapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};
  late Future<Set<Marker>> future;
  late Future<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>?> distanceFuture;
  late Stream<ShipmentDetailsRecord>? rideStream;
  late ShipmentDetailsRecord rideRecord;

  PolylinePoints? polylinePoints;
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> initialPolylines = {};
  String get googleMapsApiKey {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return widget.webGoogleMapsApiKey;
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return '';
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return widget.iOSGoogleMapsApiKey;
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return widget.androidGoogleMapsApiKey;
      default:
        return widget.webGoogleMapsApiKey;
    }
  }

  Future<Set<Marker>> generateMarkers() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    for (final location in widget.positions) {
      try {
        final url = Uri.parse(location.imageUrl.isEmpty
            ? widget.defaultImageUrl
            : location.imageUrl);
        final http.Response response = await http.get(url);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(response.bodyBytes,
              size: Size(24, 24));
          final marker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(location.toString()),
            position: latlng.LatLng(location.coordinates!.latitude,
                location.coordinates!.longitude),
            icon: icon,
            onTap: () {
              FFAppState().tapped = LatLng(location.coordinates!.latitude,
                  location.coordinates!.longitude);
              widget.rebuildPage();
            },
          );

          markers.add(marker);
        } else {
          print('Failed to load image for marker: ${url.toString()}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error in generateMarkers: ${e.toString()}');
      }
    }

    setState(() {});
    print('generateMarkers() completed with ${markers.length} markers');
    return markers.toSet();
  }

  Future<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>?> _calculateDistance({
    required double startLatitude,
    required double startLongitude,
    required double destinationLatitude,
    required double destinationLongitude,
  }) async {
    if (markers.isNotEmpty) markers.clear();

    try {

      String startCoordinatesString = '($startLatitude, $startLongitude)';
      String destinationCoordinatesString =
          '($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)';

      final http.Response startResponse =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.startImageUrl));
      final http.Response destinationResponse =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.destinationImageUrl));

      final startIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
          startResponse.bodyBytes,
          size: Size(12, 12));
      final destinationIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
          destinationResponse.bodyBytes,
          size: Size(24, 24));

      // Destination Location Marker
      Marker destinationMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(destinationCoordinatesString),
        position: latlng.LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),

        onTap: () {
          print("tapping route view static");
          FFAppState().tapped =
              LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
          widget.rebuildPage();
        },
        icon: destinationIcon,
      );

      // Adding the markers to the list
      markers.add(destinationMarker);

      // Calculating to check that the position relative
      // to the frame, and pan & zoom the camera accordingly.
      double miny = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? startLatitude
          : destinationLatitude;
      double minx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? startLongitude
          : destinationLongitude;
      double maxy = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? destinationLatitude
          : startLatitude;
      double maxx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? destinationLongitude
          : startLongitude;

      double southWestLatitude = miny;
      double southWestLongitude = minx;

      double northEastLatitude = maxy;
      double northEastLongitude = maxx;

      // Accommodate the two locations within the
      // camera view of the map
      mapController?.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
            northeast: latlng.LatLng(northEastLatitude, northEastLongitude),
            southwest: latlng.LatLng(southWestLatitude, southWestLongitude),
          ),
          60.0,
        ),
      );

      final result = await _createPolylines(
        startLatitude,
        startLongitude,
        destinationLatitude,
        destinationLongitude,
      );

      final polylines = result.item1;
      final polylineCoordinates = result.item2;

      double totalDistance = 0.0;

      for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
        totalDistance += _coordinateDistance(
          polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude,
        );
      }

      final placeDistance = totalDistance.toStringAsFixed(2);
      // debugPrint('MAP::DISTANCE: $placeDistance km');
      FFAppState().update(() {
        FFAppState().routeDistance = '$placeDistance km';
      });

      var url = Uri.parse('CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL_TO_SKIP_CORS');
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'origins': ['$startLatitude,$startLongitude'],
          'destinations': ['$destinationLatitude,$destinationLongitude'],
          'key': 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        debugPrint('$jsonResponse');
        final String durationText =
            jsonResponse['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
        debugPrint('MAP::$durationText');
        FFAppState().update(() {
          FFAppState().routeDuration = '$durationText';
        });
      } else {
        debugPrint('ERROR in distance matrix API');
      }
      debugPrint('Polylines returned here : $polylines');
      return polylines;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }


  double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

  Future<Tuple2<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>, List<latlng.LatLng>>>
      _createPolylines(
    double startLatitude,
    double startLongitude,
    double destinationLatitude,
    double destinationLongitude,
  ) async {
    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    final url = Uri.parse(
        'CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL_TO_SKIP_CORS');

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'origin': '$startLatitude,$startLongitude',
        'destination': '$destinationLatitude,$destinationLongitude',
        'key': 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
      }),
    );
    List<dynamic> polylinePointsJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    debugPrint("polylinePointsJson : ${polylinePointsJson}");
    List<latlng.LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    if (polylinePointsJson.isNotEmpty) {
      polylinePointsJson.forEach((point) {
        double latitude = point[0];
        double longitude = point[1];
        polylineCoordinates.add(latlng.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
      });
    }
    PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: widget.lineColor,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 3,
    );
    //polylines[id] = polyline;
    debugPrint('polylines true $polyline and id : $id');

    return Tuple2({id: polyline}, polylineCoordinates);
  }

  initPolylines() async {
    debugPrint("Initializing Polylines");
    double startLatitude = widget.startCoordinate.latitude;
    double startLongitude = widget.startCoordinate.longitude;

    double destinationLatitude = widget.endCoordinate.latitude;
    double destinationLongitude = widget.endCoordinate.longitude;
    final initPolylines = await _calculateDistance(
      startLatitude: startLatitude,
      startLongitude: startLongitude,
      destinationLatitude: destinationLatitude,
      destinationLongitude: destinationLongitude,
    );
    debugPrint('InitPolylines : $initPolylines');
    if (initPolylines != null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
            initialPolylines = initPolylines;
          }));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint("initState started");
    future = generateMarkers();
    debugPrint("generateMarkers future set");

    final startCoordinate = latlng.LatLng(
      widget.startCoordinate.latitude,
      widget.startCoordinate.longitude,
    );
    _initialLocation = CameraPosition(target: startCoordinate);
    debugPrint("Before Stream");
    rideStream = ShipmentDetailsRecord.getDocument(widget.rideDetailsReference);
    if (rideStream != null) {
      rideStream!.listen((value) {
        print("value listen");
        if (value != null) {
          rideRecord = value;
          print(rideRecord.toString());
        }
        print("finished listening");
      });
    }

    super.initState();
    debugPrint("initState completed");
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ShipmentDetailsRecord>(
      stream: rideStream!.distinct(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          debugPrint("No data in snapshot");
          return Container(
            height: widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            child: GoogleMap(
              markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
              initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
              myLocationEnabled: false,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(initialPolylines.values),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                mapController = controller;
                await initPolylines();
                debugPrint("Polylines initialized");
              },
            ),
          );
        }

        final rideRecord = snapshot.data;
       
        return Container(
          height: widget.height,
          width: widget.width,
          child: FutureBuilder<Map<PolylineId, Polyline>?>(
              future: _calculateDistance(
                startLatitude: rideRecord!.driverLocation!.latitude,
                startLongitude: rideRecord.driverLocation!.longitude,
                destinationLatitude: rideRecord.destinationLocation!.latitude,
                destinationLongitude: rideRecord.destinationLocation!.longitude,
              ),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print("future builder: ");
                if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                  debugPrint("Return v 3");
                  return GoogleMap(
                    markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: latlng.LatLng(
                        rideRecord!.destinationLocation!.latitude,
                        rideRecord.destinationLocation!.longitude,
                      ),
                    ),
                    myLocationEnabled: false,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                    mapToolbarEnabled: true,
                    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(snapshot.data!.values),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      mapController = controller;
                    },
                  );
                }
                debugPrint("Return v 4");
                return GoogleMap(
                  markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: latlng.LatLng(
                      rideRecord!.destinationLocation!.latitude,
                      rideRecord.destinationLocation!.longitude,
                    ),
                  ),
                  myLocationEnabled: false,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(initialPolylines.values),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    mapController = controller;
                  },
                );
              }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

